# Powershell script to execute different actions on multiple servers based on their ending domain

Tags: powershell

I've been trying for a while to write a script that would execute a few actions on ALL hosts given in a text form (coming from a .txt or .csv) --> demo:

```
 **## C:\hosts.txt**  
 - Machine4.Int.ecom.domain
 - Machine3.emea.domain.com 
 - Machine1.production.domain.com 
 - Machine2.quality.domain.com
```

The task of the script ideally is by using Get-Date

```
Clear-Host

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = @("90","30","14","7")                    ## THIS LINE SHOULD BE DEPENDING DOMAIN IN HOSTNAME

$TargetFolder = @("C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Downloads","C:\Windows\Temp","C:\Windows\CCMCache")
$Extension = @("*.vhk*","*.txt*")
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)

$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
```

For example, let's say I have the following hostnames:

- Machine1.production.domain.com
- Machine2.quality.domain.com
- Machine3.emea.domain.com
- Machine4.Int.ecom.domain

Now, based on the domains ***".production" or ".quality" or ".emea" or ".int"*** I would like to perform the following actions.

- In Production servers -> Delete files older than 90 days.
- In Quality servers -> Delete files older than 30 days.
- In emea servers ->Delete files older than 14 days.
- In INT servers -> Delete files older than 7 days.

After deleting, it would also save the file paths in a CSV file, so that I can double-check and restore them if necessary.

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using a text file containing the servers, you could add use switch inside the loop where you go through the servers and set the cleanup reference date there:

```
$servers       = Get-Content -Path 'C:\hosts.txt'
$targetFolders = "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Downloads","C:\Windows\Temp","C:\Windows\CCMCache"
$extensions    = "*.vhk","*.txt"
$today         = (Get-Date).Date

foreach ($machine in $servers) {
    # determine the reference date by the machine's name
    $refDate = switch -Regex ($machine) {
        '\.production\.' { $today.AddDays(-90); break }
        '\.quality\.'    { $today.AddDays(-30); break }
        '\.emea\.'       { $today.AddDays(-14); break }
        '\.int\.'        { $today.AddDays(-7) }
    }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock {
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $using:targetFolders -File -Include $using:extensions -Recurse | 
                 Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $using:refDate}
        # do your clean-up here on the files you have gathered
        # maybe write a log first or simply delete these files?
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Theo. Thanks for the idea, i've tried to addapt some of these approaches and taken yours as a new base. Will try to see if i can somehow re-arrange some of the things i was initially thinking of and make it work. Ideally in the next hours i'll reply you back :)

Comment: @FourZeroOne Please do. Remember that when using regex, you must escape all characters that have special meaning in regex, like the dot by prefixing them with a backslash as I have also done.